# Vue - timing of child computed vs. parent computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Components `<parent>` and `<child>` both reference a property in Vuex via `computed`. `<parent>` has a `v-if` that prevents `<child>` from being rendered if the property is `null`. `<child>`, in turn, relies on the property not being `null` and throws an error if it is.

Now when I set the property to `null` in Vuex, the `<child>` throws an error because the property is `null`. So apparently, the child's `computed` is evaluated before the parent's. This is against my expectation, as I would have thought the parent's `computed` gets evaluated first, sees that the value is `null`, and then doesn't render the child anymore which in turn doesn't error.

How do I know which computed's are evaluated first, since I can't find any docs about it, and is there a way to influence the order?

Comment: without code, it's like expecting a mechanic to fix your car over the phone :p it can be done, but a LOT of questions need to be asked - while it seems obvious that this is a vue2 question (since you're using vuex) - can you add the vue2 tag to your question - as stipulated in the description of the vue.js tag :p

Comment: Made the question more specific and added the tag, thanks.

Comment: Makes sense, but you generally shouldn't allow this scenario exactly for this reason. It's not documented afaik and deduced from the actual behaviour. Mount lifecycle is known to be ordered from a child to a parent, I suppose it's the same here. Either move v-if to a child, or pass a value that a child depends on through a prop, since it's already available in a parent

Comment: Thank you @EstusFlask, your comment fully answers my question. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: Glad you sorted this out. Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario generally shouldn't be allowed because this may in unintended race condition. The order in which parent and children components are updated is not documented but can be observed based on the actual behaviour.

`mounted` lifecycle is known to be ordered from a child to a parent, so `update` could be expected to be ordered the same way. Also `v-if` can provide additional delay because the changes are applied on component update.

`v-if` can be either moved to a child, or a value that a child depends can be passed through a prop instead of being accessed from a store directly, since it's already available in parent template and used in `v-if`.